# Using sliders in plotly with date ranges

Tags: plotly, slider

I have a series of x and y data recorded at given dates. How do I create a plot in plotly where I can use a slider to slide through the end dates.
i.e. start date = 01/01/22 (datetime variable)
end date = 01/01/23 (datetime variable)

I want to adjust my range from 01/01/22 to xx, with xx being chosen by the user.

I have had issues with examples on plotly website.
Do I need to use Dash to create a slider using datetime variables?

Comment: It can be handled plotly. Please refer to the reference for an [example](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#time-series-with-range-slider) of a range slider with time series data on the x-axis.